# How to traverse camera from device via adb to my Ubuntu?

Tags: adb, usb, camera, linux

What is the best way to traverse web camera?

E.g. there is great number of web servers for android with video translations. How to get access to its via adb?

Or wi-fi would be a easiest way?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to implement web-camera for Ubuntu from my Android device.

Comment: It's not possible to use `adb` for this, but I'm sure you can find an app for your phone to do this.

Comment: @spiffymoo, 1-2 days, I will try it. Could you please put a little answer, I will fill it with complete cites of how-to do web-cam from android device, and will accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @spiffymoo, looks like there is no source code.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the smartphone via USB, start the [IP camera server app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) and use adb port forwarding or usb tethering to access the server from PC.

Then you can connect directly to the mjpeg video stream at `http://yourphoneip:8080/video`.

[This script](https://github.com/bluezio/ipwebcam-gst) also creates a v4l virtual device if you need it.

I've measured that the streaming latency is a bit higher than a regular USB camera (<500ms vs <100ms).